# Como ler dois vetores e colocar os valores em um terceiro vetor e em ordem crescente?

Tags: c

o enunciado do problema é o seguinte: Faça um programa que leia um valor inteiro N. Após isso, leia N valores inteiros colocando-os em um vetor A de tamanho N. Em seguida, leia um valor inteiro M. Então, leia M valores inteiros colocando-os em um vetor B de tamanho M. Assuma que A e B sempre estarão ordenados de forma crescente.

O programa deve juntar os valores de A e B em um vetor C, de forma que C também esteja ordenado. Ao final, escreva o vetor C resultante. Não é permitido utilizar algoritmo de ordenação.

eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int N;
  scanf("%d", &N);

  int vetorA[N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);
  }

  int M;
  scanf("%d", &M);

  int vetorB[M];
  for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
    scanf("%d", &vetorB[j]);
  }

  int *vetorC;
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;

  vetorC = (int *)(malloc(100 * sizeof(int)));

  if(vetorC == NULL){
    printf("\n erro ao alocar memoria");
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < (M + N); i++){
    if (vetorA[j] < vetorB[k]) {
      vetorC[i] = vetorA[j];
      j++;
    }
    else if(vetorB[k] < vetorA[j]){
      vetorC[i] = vetorB[k];
      k++;
    }

    else{
      vetorC[i] = vetorA[j];
      j++;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < (M + N); i++){
    printf("%d ", vetorC[i]);
  }
  
  free(vetorC);

}
```

mas o programa sempre printa errado no final.
um exemplo de input:
4
1 2 7 8
3
3 4 7
a saída deveria ser:
1 2 3 4 7 7 8
mas minha saída é:
1 2 3 4 7 7 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é que, quando j atinge o valor "M", todos os valores de vetorA já foram utilizados, então vetorA[j] está apontando para um valor aleatório, fora do limite da matriz.

O programa poderia quebrar, mas para seu azar não quebrou, e ainda pegou um valor aleatório igual  a um digitado, o que faz parecer que o problema é outro.

A parte relevante ficaria assim, salvo melhor juízo:

```
if (j >= N) {
  // vetorA esgotado
  vetorC[i] = vetorB[k];
  k++;
} else if (k >= M) {
  // vetorB esgotado
  vetorC[i] = vetorA[j];
  j++;
} else if (vetorA[j] <= vetorB[k]) {
  vetorC[i] = vetorA[j];
  j++;
} else if (vetorB[k] < vetorA[j]){
  vetorC[i] = vetorB[k];
  k++;
}
```

Note ainda que simplifiquei o caso de vetorA[j]  igual a vetorB[j].